# Group By/Order By mysql

Tags: mysql

I've got a table containing customer id's and purchase dates, I'm grouping by customer but I want the last purchase date to show not the first purchase date

I've tried

GROUP BY customer

ORDER BY purchasedate DESC

Comment: Post your actual query. I suspect you are applying a `GROUP BY` to only one column of many in your select list, which MySQL permits (where other RDBMS wouldn't).  You'll likely need a `MAX()` aggregate somewhere.

Comment: Can you post your entire SQL statement?

Comment: The fact that mySql permits that nonsense is a complete disgrace..

Comment: @MikeChristensen I wouldn't go so far as a disgrace, but it is a definite tripping point for people who learn aggregates from MySQL and then move on to find their methods fail in every other RDBMS...

Comment: Nope, it's spitting in the face of the SQL gods.  As far as I'm concerned, the fact this is permitted is an unintended side-effect of the original implementation; a bug that was never caught, and a behavior that may or may not change or be fixed to conform to standards in future versions.  At the very least, I would *never* write production code that *depended* on this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Which purchase date do you need? If last purchase date, then query should be like this:

```
SELECT *, max(purchasedate) FROM table1 GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is poor practice. You should always specify a column list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to post your actual query as well as context for us to assist you better.

It seems as though you are missing the aggregate. You can try this:

```
SELECT customer, MAX(purchasedate)
FROM sparkles
GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: `FROM sparkles LEFT JOIN unicorns ON sparkles.luminescence = unicorns.rainbow_radius`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I try to *inject* sparkles and unicorns where I can.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your actual query, you might be able to use something similar to this:

```
select t1.customerid, t1.purchasedate, t1.othercol1, t1.othercol2, t1.othercol3
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
    select max(purchasedate) purchasedate, customerid
    from yourtable
    group by customerid
) t2
    on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
    and t1.purchasedate = t2.purchasedate
order by t1.purchasedate desc
```

Or you can apply the `max()` aggregate function to the `purchasedate` column